# Update a price field on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, price

i'm trying to do a function activate on load page, this function is to get a number value in "input#quantity" and calculate "input.final-price" on page load activating function currentPrice. But on page load is not updating the field when the page load.

```js
function currentPrice() {
  var priceProduct = parseFloat($.trim($('span.price').html().replace(",", "").replace("$", ""))); 
  var convertion = ((priceProduct)/100).toFixed(2);
  var price = parseFloat($("input#quantity").val());
  var total = ((convertion) * (price)).toFixed(2);
  $("input.final-price").val(total);
  }
// Onload
$(document).on("load", "input", currentPrice);
```

Comment: So whats the issue?

Comment: This $(document).on("load", "input", currentPrice);
is not updating the field on the page load.

Comment: Use $(document).ready(function (){ currentPrice();});

Comment: This is working when i test the code outside the website, when i implement this don't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait till the document loaded then run your function

```
$(function(){
    currentPrice();
});
```

The above is shorthand for $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

I've made some assumptions about your markup (see demo below); note that the `.final-price` reference is now an ID (`#final-price`) rather than a class (as this makes binding up the associated `<label>` easier).

I've also assumed you want the final price (read-only) to stay updated in the event that a new quantity is entered.

```js
function currentPrice() {
  var priceProduct = parseFloat($.trim($('span.price').html().replace(",", "").replace("$", "")));
  var convertion = ((priceProduct) / 100).toFixed(2);
  var price = parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
  var total = ((convertion) * (price)).toFixed(2);
  $("#final-price").val(total);
}

$(function() {
  // initialise final figure
  currentPrice();
  
  // ensure total is updated each time quantity is changed
  $("#quantity").on("keyup", currentPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price">$38,000</span>

<label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
<input id="quantity" value="5" />

<label for="final-price">Final</label>
<input id="final-price" readonly />
```